# Can't get ApiGateway Lambda:InvokeFunction permissions working in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to set up a CloudFormation template that will create a lambda function and an APIGateway that can access it. However, despite setting up the Lambda:InvokeFunction permission as shown below (and trying every permutation under the sun as recommended on other SO questions), I get the message `Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function.`

The only way I can get it to work is if I go into the AWS console and manually un-set and re-set the APIGateway's destination to the lambda.

I've also tried the CLI to no effect:

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name $updatedFunction.FunctionName --statement-id "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway" --action "lambda:InvokeFunction" --principal "apigateway.amazonaws.com" --source-arn $api.StackId
```

Does anyone have any insight into why these permissions wouldn't work?

```
...  
"Get":{
     "Type":"AWS::Lambda::Function",
     "Properties":{
        "Code":{
           "S3Bucket":"webapistack-bucket-org0oolyde9v",
           "S3Key":"webapi/webapistack-636349410359047808.zip"
        },
        "Tags":[
           {
              "Value":"SAM",
              "Key":"lambda:createdBy"
           }
        ],
        "MemorySize":256,
        "Environment":{
           "Variables":{
              "AppS3Bucket":{
                 "Fn::If":[
                    "CreateS3Bucket",
                    {
                       "Ref":"Bucket"
                    },
                    {
                       "Ref":"BucketName"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           }
        },
        "Handler":"webapi::webapi.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync",
        "Role":{
           "Fn::GetAtt":[
              "GetRole",
              "Arn"
           ]
        },
        "Timeout":30,
        "Runtime":"dotnetcore1.0"
     }
},      
"GetPutResourcePermissionTest":{
  "Type":"AWS::Lambda::Permission",
  "Properties":{
     "Action":"lambda:invokeFunction",
     "Principal":"apigateway.amazonaws.com",
     "FunctionName":{
        "Ref":"Get"
     },
     "SourceArn":{
        "Fn::Sub":[
           "arn:aws:execute-api:WS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${__ApiId__}/${__Stage__}/ANY/*",
           {
              "__Stage__":"*",
              "__ApiId__":{
                 "Ref":"ServerlessRestApi"
              }
           }
        ]
     }
  }
},
...
"ServerlessRestApi":{
   "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
   "Properties":{
      "Body":{
         "info":{
            "version":"1.0",
            "title":{
               "Ref":"AWS::StackName"
            }
         },
         "paths":{
            "/{proxy+}":{
               "x-amazon-apigateway-any-method":{
                  "x-amazon-apigateway-integration":{
                     "httpMethod":"POST",
                     "type":"aws_proxy",
                     "uri":{
               "Fn::Sub":"arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${Get.Arn}/invocations"
                       }
                    },
                    "responses":{

                    }
                 }
              }
           },
           "swagger":"2.0"
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AWS::Lambda::Permission` seems to be incorrect.

The FunctionName you are referencing is the logical ID, the spec, however, requires the physical ID or ARN.

The SourceArn pattern of the Sub is missing some characters on the Region replacement.

Since I'm not sure whether the "ANY"-operation is valid for the ARN, I would replace it with "*", just to be sure.

Here a changed version of the permission:

```
"GetPutResourcePermissionTest":{
  "Type":"AWS::Lambda::Permission",
  "Properties":{
     "Action":"lambda:invokeFunction",
     "Principal":"apigateway.amazonaws.com",
     "FunctionName":{
        "Fn::GetAtt": [ "Get" , "Arn" ]
     },
     "SourceArn":{
        "Fn::Sub":[
           "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${__ApiId__}/${__Stage__}/*/*",
           {
              "__Stage__":"*",
              "__ApiId__":{
                 "Ref":"ServerlessRestApi"
              }
           }
        ]
     }
  }
},
```

Comment: This worked - thanks. A note for anyone else - the ANY operator also had to be removed as mentioned.